# How to force to create a single thread using scheduledexecutorservice and avoid multithreading

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-threads

I would like to execute the following JAVA code only once when I enter to welcome.jsp page.

welcome.jsp:

```
<%WeeklyScheduledMail wsm = WeeklyScheduledMail.INSTANCE;
wsm.startThread(); %>
```

So, if a user access to the website once the server is initiated, that code can be used once, and the other users who log in and access to welcome.jsp will not execute that JAVA code.

First, I tried to implement the Singleton pattern with enum, I thought it would be enough but it did not work. I also tried the Synchronized keyword for the methods but nothing...

I'm sure I did something wrong or there is a better way to do what I want to do.

Some portions of the code:

WeeklyScheduledMail.java:

```
public enum WeeklyScheduledMail{

    INSTANCE;

    public void startThread() {

        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = 
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        Runnable task = new TaskSendEmail();
        int initialDelay = 0;
        int periodicDelay = 10;
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, initialDelay, periodicDelay, 
        TimeUnit.SECONDS);          

    }
}
```

TaskSendEmail.java:

```
public class TaskSendEmail implements Runnable{

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello: "+System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

Comment: Try Webapplication event i.e `contextInitialized()` this will run only once

Comment: It doesn't seem like a good idea to manage this kind of functionality from the JSP, it should done on application startup.

Comment: @daniu I think so too, but I need to 'trigger' this Java code when some user with specific role (administrator) access to the welcome.jsp page.

Comment: @Arvind Interesting! Could you illustrate the process a bit? It does not have to be with my code, just a more developed example to understand how to implement it.

Comment: @Gera, kindly refer to post https://stackoverflow.com/a/50129252/2575725 actualy does the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking into the incorrect concept to run application initialization code. JSPs and other resources exposed to the user aren't designed for this. Even if you can force some lazy initialization logic, there will still be avoidable overhead.

What you're looking for is provided by JavaEE: a [context listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html), which is invoked once on application startup to notify your application that the context has been initialized:

```
public class MyContextListener implements javax.servlet.ServletContextListener {

    private static fWeeklyScheduledMail wsm = 
            weeklyScheduledMail.INSTANCE;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
            wsm.startThread();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        wsm.stopThread();
    }
}
```

This listener must then be registered in the `web.xml` deployment descriptor (under `web-app`):

```
<listener>
     <listener-class>my.packg.MyContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The above code and configuration will cause your schedule to run once, when the application starts.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot.

But, I would like to know if it would be possible to perform similar tasks (one thread or multiple threads) if some specific event occur.

The listener is initializing the thread when the server starts, but...what if I want the thread to be initialized once a specific event happens within the webapp?

Comment: @Gera What's the type of those other events?

Comment: i.e When a user with admin rol clicks a button inside of a specific page.

Comment: @Gera No, you can use "events" for that. For that, normal application code (servlet `doXyz1, JSF listener, etc) should be used. You have event listeners for user sessions as well, but no listener is designed for handling user interaction.